# RichTextBox selected Text property

Tags: c#, winforms

I've a RTB in my form to bold half of its text. Code is

```
        int start = richTextBox.Text.ToUpper().IndexOf(text.ToUpper());
        richTextBox.Select(start, text.Length);
        richTextBox.SelectionFont = new Font(richTextBox.Font.Name, richTextBox.Font.Size, richTextBox.Font.Style ^ FontStyle.Bold);
```

and I am using `MenuItem` class to add custom menu's in my form. One of the menu is `Copy Selected` will be having `event handler` which triggers when user select that menu to clipboard for pasting selected text.

Issue is when user doesn't select any text and tries to paste, it is pasting the selected text which i made for bold(above in RTB) which is a bug. code in my handler

```
 void noteCopySelectedMenu_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (sender != null)
        {
            MenuItem noteCopyMenu = (MenuItem)sender;
            ContextMenu noteContextMenu = (ContextMenu)noteCopyMenu.Parent;
            RichTextBox text = (RichTextBox)noteContextMenu.SourceControl;
            if (text != null)
            {
                // Copy note to Clipboard
                Clipboard.Clear();
                Clipboard.SetDataObject(text.SelectedText, false);
            }
        }
    }
```

`text.SelectedText` is holding the text of bold from RTB
When user simply select menu without selecting any text, it should be empty. How to overcome this??

Answer (score 0):

You can modify your code like this and put additional checks:

```
        if (text != null && text.SelectionLength > 0)
        {
            // Copy note to Clipboard
            Clipboard.Clear();
            Clipboard.SetDataObject(text.SelectedText, false);
        }
```

Comment: it still have the Length of text i've taken for Bold....so condition is getting through when user doesn't select any text